# Search results incorrect for F#

Tags: bug, search, tag-search

On looking for `F#` I realized that results are wrong - looking for `[F#]` gives correct results though.
My first thought was that it may have something to do with the `'#'` character but
for `'c#'`, for example,  it does not matter whether square brackets are included or not - the results are always the same.

Grateful for SO as it is. Will use it regardless this issue will be classified as a bug or a feature and far from pointing fingers at anybody.
It just seems to me that providing consistent behaviour for `'f#'` searches as for `'c#'` searches  will make SO even better.

Comment: `"f#"` returns better results? Almost expect there is a line like this in the codebase `if (search == "c#") { search = "[c#]"; }`

Answer (score 10):

When you search for just `c#` it gets converted in a tag search because the SE search engine is programmed to treat the search string as a tag when a search string is one of the top 60 tags of the SE site. `C#` is in the top tag list whereas `F#` is not, so it is treated as a regular search.

So if you want to search for the word `c#` and not the tag then type `"c#"` as the search term.

> Any individual search terms which map directly to the top 40 tags will be auto-converted to tag searches. So if you enter
> c++ entities
>
> it will convert to
>
> [c++] entities
>
> automagically on your behalf.

**Source: [Stack Overflow Search – Now 61% Less Crappy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/)**

**Update:** Based on [Nick Craver's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146311/why-are-search-queries-inconsistently-converted-into-tags/146312?noredirect=1#comment780562_146312), the value *40* has been changed to top **60** tags.

Comment: So what you are saying is SO cannot do full text search queries by design? For as innocent query term as "F#" and natural language processing tools like nltk and the likes, I hardly see any challenges to do mapping of exact search terms to tags.

Comment: @matcheek For an exact match, you may enclose the search term in quotes, like `"f#"`

Comment: yes I am aware of that. For me it's just slightly shocking that, given the potential accumulated on SO, such a trivial thing, which it is, has not been addressed yet. And we are not even talking about sofisticated stemmers and some AI running on top. It's basic one-to-one mapping.

Comment: @matcheek I am not sure if it is due to any technical limitation, I guess they just didn't want to do it that way. Some more info related to the search engine is available here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange